# What is the precise relationship between $\mathcal{N}_{D/X}$ and $\mathcal{N}_{q(D)/Y}$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be smooth and projective, $D$ is an Cartier divisor of $X$. $\mathcal{N}_{D/X}$ is the normal bundle of $D$ in $X$.
Let $q: X\longrightarrow Y$  be a finite quotient map of degree $d$. And $q$ is totally ramified along $D$, with ramification index $r$.  $q(D)$ is the image of $D$. Let $\mathcal{N}_{q(D)/Y}$ be the normal bundle of $q(D)$ in $Y$. My question is, what is the precise relationship between $\mathcal{N}_{D/X}$ and $\mathcal{N}_{q(D)/Y}$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give more information.  Is $Y$ smooth? Is $Y$ normal?  Is $q(D)$ a Cartier divisor in $Y$?  If $q$ is totally ramified along $D$ with ramification index $r$, does that mean that $r$ equals $d-1$?  Or, perhaps, do you mean something else by "totally ramified"?